# user authentication with `react-router-dom`?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I have a requirement where I have to render a component if a user is `loggedIn` there are two conditions

1: If a user is `loggedin` don't show `somecomponent` // This I have achieved

2: But there are some `component` which I have to render even if user is not in `loggedin` mode.

**problem statement**: How to access which component is rendering,at runtime

***my approach : catch it with url***

```
if (this.props.match.url == '/someulr'){
  // code for no authntication
}

 but what if a url is like this '/someurl/:id' // where id is variable
```

applying regex is not a good idea any idea for this

Comment: This is lacking information, however, I would wrap any routes that require authentication in a component for example `Auth` which on `mount` or/and `update` checks if the user is authenticated if not then `redirect` them to `login` or wherever non-authenticated users should go.

Comment: This wrapping things I have done. One  part which is wrapped in auth and other part is not wrapped in auth but at run time only one part has to be executed how to  achieve this because at run time I have only one thing that is url

Comment: Please can you add your routes component to your question.